# Left join usando Linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Tengo la  tabla persona en  la cual existen 100 personas de las cuales 80 son alumnos, de esos 80 solo 50 son matriculados, intento  hacer una `left join` (Sql Server) para que me muestre el alumno que existe, aun cuando no estén matriculados

***La tabla que almacena la informacion del curso, paralelo, turno es `MATRICULA`***

```
var persona = (from p in db.Persona                                             // cantidad de Personas _________________________ 100
                join co in db.Colegio on p.CodColegio equals co.IdColegio        
                join al in db.Alumno on p.CodPersona equals al.CodPersona        // cantidad de personas que son alumnos___________ 80

                join ma in db.Matricula on al.CodAlumno equals ma.CodAlumno      // cantidad de añumnos que estan matriculados ___  50

                join cu in db.Curso on ma.CodCurso equals cu.CodCurso            // los _ 50 _ tienen curso asignado
                join pa in db.Paralelo on ma.CodParalelo equals pa.CodParalelo   // los _ 50 _ tienen paralelo asignado
                join tu in db.Turno on ma.CodTurno equals tu.CodTurno            // los _ 50 _ tienen turno asignado

                where p.NombreCompleto.ToUpper().Replace(" ", string.Empty) == nombre.ToUpper().Replace(" ", string.Empty)

                select new
                {
                    CodPersona       = p.CodPersona,
                    NombreCompleto   = p.NombreCompleto,

                    CodColegio       = p.CodColegio,
                    colegio          = co.Nombre,

                    curso            = cu.Descripcion,
                    paralelo         = pa.Descripcion,
                    turno            = tu.Descripcion
                }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: disculpa pero sin conocer mucho de linq, yo lo que ahi veo es un inner join, hasta donde se la sintáxis sería `LEFT JOIN` no?

Comment: correcto, ahi  tengo inner joins, que en lo que solo me ayuda es en encontrar alumnos que estenmatriculados,  el  detalle es que no hallo  la manera de hacer un left :( @shadow

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Con el método `DefaultIfEmpty()` puedes hacer un left join, te pongo un ejemplo con `Persona` y `Colegio`

```
from p in db.Persona 
join co in db.Colegio on p.CodColegio equals co.IdColegio into PersonasColegio
from pco in PersonasColegio.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
    //lo que quieras seleccionar
}
```

Comment: Hola, me gustaria entender bien, como armaste el left join, lei la docu pero igualmente me pierdo en `into`, segun lei sirve generar otra consulta despues del `select`, podrias explicarme la logica? entiendo la primer parte donde haces un inner join pero la verdad despues ni idea de la logica.

Comment: Hola, la palabra `into` sirve para identificar la query, puedes verlo como una especie de variable en la que se guarda la query que has hecho, en este caso se guarda el inner join dentro de `PersonasColegio`, y luego, se aplica la función `DefaultIfEmpty()`, que te incluye los valores vacíos del inner join y los devuelve como null, consiguiendo así un left join

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, estuve haciendo pruebas, me falta entender el `DefaultIfEmpty` yo pensaba que default era alternativo, pero el left join se rompe si no lo pongo, en cuanto al `into` entendi bien como funciona, si no es molestia podrias comentarme algo mas acerca de dafaultempty?.

Comment: Si no pones el `DefaultIfEmpty` obtienes un inner join, lo que hace esta función es devolver un elemento por defecto, en este caso null, cuando la secuencia está vacía. Al hacer un inner join, los elementos de la tabla de la izquierda que no están enlazados con ningún elemento de la tabla de la derecha, tienen un enlace vacío, por lo que al poner la función `DefaultIfEmpty`, los devuelve como null. Puedes echarle un vistazo a la documentación [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 2):

Creo que puede hacer esto

```
var query = (from p in db.Persona                                             // cantidad de Personas _________________________ 100
        join co in db.Colegio on p.CodColegio equals co.IdColegio
           into PersonaColegio
        from pc in PersonaColegio.DefaultIfEmpty() // LEFT JOIN
        join al in db.Alumno on p.CodPersona equals al.CodPersona        // cantidad de personas que son alumnos___________ 80

        join ma in db.Matricula on al.CodAlumno equals ma.CodAlumno      // cantidad de añumnos que estan matriculados ___  50

        join cu in db.Curso on ma.CodCurso equals cu.CodCurso            // los _ 50 _ tienen curso asignado
        join pa in db.Paralelo on ma.CodParalelo equals pa.CodParalelo   // los _ 50 _ tienen paralelo asignado
        join tu in db.Turno on ma.CodTurno equals tu.CodTurno            // los _ 50 _ tienen turno asignado

        where p.NombreCompleto.ToUpper().Replace(" ", string.Empty) == nombre.ToUpper().Replace(" ", string.Empty)

        select new
        {
            codPersona = p.CodPersona,
            nombreCompleto = p.NombreCompleto,

            codColegio = p.CodColegio,
            colegio = pc.Nombre,

            curso = cu.Descripcion,
            paralelo = pa.Descripcion,
            turno = tu.Descripcion
        });
```

-------- SQL Query

```
 SELECT
     [Extent1].[CodColegio] AS[CodColegio], 
     [Extent1].[CodPersona] AS[CodPersona], 
     [Extent1].[NombreCompleto] AS[NombreCompleto], 
     [Extent2].[Nombre] AS[Nombre], 
     [Extent5].[Descripcion] AS[Descripcion], 
     [Extent6].[Descripcion] AS[Descripcion1], 
     [Extent7].[Descripcion]
         AS[Descripcion2]
 FROM[dbo].[Personas]
         AS[Extent1]
 LEFT OUTER JOIN[dbo].[Colegios] AS[Extent2] ON[Extent1].[CodColegio] = [Extent2].[IdColegio]
         INNER JOIN[dbo].[Alumnoes] AS[Extent3] ON[Extent1].[CodPersona] = [Extent3].[CodPersona]
         INNER JOIN[dbo].[Matriculas] AS[Extent4] ON[Extent3].[CodAlumno] = [Extent4].[CodAlumno]
         INNER JOIN[dbo].[Cursoes] AS[Extent5] ON[Extent4].[CodCurso] = [Extent5].[CodCurso]
         INNER JOIN[dbo].[Paraleloes] AS[Extent6] ON[Extent4].[CodParalelo] = [Extent6].[CodParalelo]
         INNER JOIN[dbo].[Turnoes] AS[Extent7] ON[Extent4].[CodTurno] = [Extent7].[CodTurno]
         WHERE((REPLACE(UPPER([Extent1].[NombreCompleto]), N' ', @p__linq__0)) = (REPLACE(UPPER(@p__linq__1), N' ', @p__linq__2))) OR((REPLACE(UPPER([Extent1].[NombreCompleto]), N' ', @p__linq__0) IS NULL) AND(REPLACE(UPPER(@p__linq__1), N' ', @p__linq__2) IS NULL))
```

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo sacar la SQL generada por LinQ en .Net Core 3? Gracias.

Comment: @Zindokar  puedes user `SQL Server Proviler`

Comment: Hola Fredy, al final lo conseguí con un `IloggerFactory`, uso `PostgreSQL` de todos modos. Otra manera es ver en la base de datos cuáles son las últimas SQL ejecutadas, cuando lo he usado con `Oracle 11g` me venía bien, que supongo que será algo parecido al `SQL Server Proviler`